# How to pass as arguments the element itself and the event in the same function

Tags: javascript

I have a inline event handler like `<div onclick="checkFunction()">`. I know if I want to pass the element I use this keyword, but besides the element, I wanna pass the event because I have other elements inside this div and I wanna do some things whit it based on the event.target. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest never using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, but if you're using them, the way you do it is to pass `event`:

```html
<div onclick="checkFunction(this, event)">`
```

The handler's first argument is the element, the second is the event.

That style of handler executes in an environment where `event` is in scope, either because it's a local variable (all modern browsers) or it's a global one (old Microsoft IE) (or both, since the global is now in the specification and even Firefox added it in the end). Either way, it's in scope for the code in the quotes, so you can use it to pass the event to the event handler function as its second argument.

---

But that style of handler can only call global functions, which is one reason to avoid them, and certain function names will mess you up (like `animate`), which is another reason to avoid them. Instead, I suggest hooking up the handler with `addEventListener`:

```html
<div id="some-id">`
```

```js
document.getElementById("some-id").addEventListener(checkFunction);
// ...
function checkFunction(event) {
    // Here you can use `this` or `event.currentTarget` to access the element,
    // and `event` to access the event
    // ...
}
```

You **do not** need to use an `id`, you just need some means of identifying the element. You can use any CSS selector with `querySelector` instead of using `getElementById`.

Comment: Note that [`window.event`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-window-extensions) is now an official monstrosity that everyone has to implement... (and also, in SVG it used to be a local `evt` and not `event`).

Comment: @Kaiido - Yeah, I know. :-| And even Mozilla finally gave in w/Firefox. I didn't know about the SVG thing, though. Yikes.

Comment: Yes, it's in the specs, there are [wpt tests](https://wpt.fyi/results/dom/events/event-global.html?label=master&label=experimental&aligned&q=global%20event) and everything. It's just standard. A browser that wouldn't implement it would be "buggy". Regarding SVG, they did fix it in [SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/interact.html#SVGEvents) (Annotation 3).

Comment: @Kaiido - Right. The HTML and DOM specs have lots of things that are there because you'd need to have them if you were building a new browser. This change of tack was about 10 years ago, and is definitely a good thing, despite the specifics of some of the things it means end up being included.